# Change variable value in middle of JavaScript in Android

Tags: javascript, android

Further to [This](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1136236) JavaScript code, I would like to know how can I change the internal values inside the script in the middle of the running script.

This is the code that I write in order to run the script :

Java Code :

```
   @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
WebView myBrowser;
@SuppressLint("JavascriptInterface")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myBrowser = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.mybrowser);

    final MyJavaScriptInterface myJavaScriptInterface
    = new MyJavaScriptInterface(this);

    myBrowser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
    myBrowser.addJavascriptInterface(myJavaScriptInterface, "AndroidFunction");
    myBrowser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/sperm.html");
    myBrowser.loadUrl("javascript:callFromActivity(\""+50+"\")");

 // disable scroll on touch
    myBrowser.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

      public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE);
      }
    });
}
public class MyJavaScriptInterface {
      Context mContext;

         MyJavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
             mContext = c;
         }


     }
```

}

XML Code :

```
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:background="@drawable/background">
 <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"    >
    <WebView
       android:id="@+id/mybrowser"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

This is the java script :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
  background: #000;

}

ellipse {
  fill: #6633ff;
}

path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #33ccff;
  stroke-linecap: round; 

}

.mid {
  stroke-width: 4px;

}

.tail {
  stroke-width: 2px;

}

</style>
<body >
<script src="d3.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">

    var width = 700,//350,
        height = 620;

    var n = 5,
        m = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8) + 12,
        degrees = 180 / Math.PI;

    var spermatozoa = d3.range(n).map(function() {
      var x = Math.random() * width,
          y = Math.random() * height;
      return {
        vx: Math.random() * 2 - 1,
        vy: Math.random() * 2 - 1,
        path: d3.range(m).map(function() { return [x, y]; }),
        count: 0
      };
    });

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

    var g = svg.selectAll("g")
        .data(spermatozoa)
      .enter().append("g");

    var head = g.append("ellipse")
        .attr("rx", 6.5)
        .attr("ry", 4);

    g.append("path")
        .datum(function(d) { return d.path.slice(0, 3); })
        .attr("class", "mid");


    g.append("path")
        .datum(function(d) { return d.path; })
        .attr("class", "tail");

    var tail = g.selectAll("path");

    d3.timer(function() {
      for (var i = -1; ++i < n;) {
        var spermatozoon = spermatozoa[i],
            path = spermatozoon.path,
            dx = spermatozoon.vx,
            dy = 0,
            x = path[0][0] += dx,
            y = path[0][1] += dy,
            speed = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy),
            count =  4,
            k1 = -5 - speed / 1;

        // Bounce off the walls.
        if (x < 0 || x > width) spermatozoon.vx *= -1;
        if (y < 0 || y > height) spermatozoon.vy *= -1;

        // Swim!
        for (var j = 0; ++j < m;) {
          var vx = x - path[j][0],
              vy = y - path[j][1],
              k2 = Math.sin(((spermatozoon.count += count) + j * 3) / 300) / speed;
          path[j][0] = (x += dx / speed * k1) - dy * k2;
          path[j][1] = (y += dy / speed * k1) + dx * k2;
          speed = Math.sqrt((dx = vx) * dx + (dy = vy) * dy);
        }
      }

      head.attr("transform", headTransform);
      tail.attr("d", tailPath);
    });

    function headTransform(d) {
      return "translate(" + d.path[0] + ")rotate(" + 0 + ")";
    }

    function tailPath(d) {
      return "M" + d.join("L");
    }
    function callFromActivity(n1)
    { 
        n = n1;
    }

</script>
```

I trying to to change the n value from "callFromActivity" function in the javascript.

What should i change?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried changing that n value in an html page first?

Comment: No, I followed [This](http://android-er.blogspot.co.il/2011/10/call-javascript-inside-webview-from.html)  guide to do what I want, but this is doesn't work for me.

Comment: OK, first try it on HTML with a button. Find the right way to set the variable. Then use android to change it. I don't think android is the problem.